# Help with simplifying summation

Tags: summation, sorting

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector of non-negative numbers $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ with mean $\bar{x}$.
I would like to prove that

$$\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \left| x_i - x_j \right|}{2 n^2 \bar{x}} = \frac{2 \sum_{i = 1}^n i(\tilde{x}_i - \bar{x})}{n^2 \bar{x}},$$

where $\tilde{x}$ contains the same elements as $x$ but sorted in ascending order. The rhs is computationally cheaper because I don't have to compute every possible absolute difference $\left|x_i - x_j\right|$.

Can I proceed using induction or maybe a manipulation of the lhs would yield directly the rhs, what do you think? Either ways seems tedious, I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|x_i-x_j|&=2\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^n(\tilde x_j-\tilde x_i)=2\sum_{i=1}^n-\tilde x_i(n-i)+2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^n\tilde x_j\\&=2\sum_{i=1}^n-\tilde x_i(n-i)+2\sum_{i=1}^n (i-1)\tilde x_i\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-n-1)\tilde x_i\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^n2i\tilde x_i-2(\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^n\tilde x_i)\frac{n(n+1)}2\\
&=2\sum_{i=1}^n2i\tilde x_i-4\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\tilde x_i\right)\times\sum_{i=1}^ni
\end{align}
$$\boxed{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n|x_i-x_j|=4\sum_{1=1}^ni(\tilde x_i-\bar{x})}$$

***Explanation***

**Line 1**: Due to symmetry, it is unnecessary to sum all terms from $j=1$ to $n$. The term $\widetilde x_i$ is independent of $j$ so it can be taken out of the first sum to get $$\widetilde x_i \sum_{j=i+1}^n 1$$

**Line 2**: Similarly to Fubini's Theorem in calculus the two sums of the $\tilde x_j$ term in the first line can be switched while appropriately changing the boundaries. More intuitively this corresponds to adding the following terms from top to bottom (by column) instead of left to right (by row):

\begin{matrix}
x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&\cdots&x_n\\
&x_3&x_4&x_5&\cdots&x_n\\
&&x_4&x_5&\cdots&x_n\\
&&&\vdots
\end{matrix}

P.S.: The form obtained in the third line, although having the same order of complexity as the final form, is probably faster for smaller values of $n$.

Comment: Can you quickly explain the first equality? how sorting $x$ permits those chained summations?

Comment: @amrods Answer edited...

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure I understand, the ordering of $\tilde{x}$ is used in the chained summation by having $\tilde{x}_j - \tilde{x}_i$ with $j > i$, which ensures that $\tilde{x}_j \geq \tilde{x}_i$, correct? BTW, that vertical summation was very enlightening.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's like each absolute value $|x_j-x_i|$ is an element $a_{ij}$ in a symmetric matrix. We sum the terms either above or below the diagonal then multiply by two.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Comment: Btw, is this related to image processing?

Comment: No, rather income inequality. The first expression in my question is the Gini Coefficient of inequality which is $\mathbb{E}[|x_i - x_j|]/(2\mu)$, a measure of inequality of income in a population.